# C++: How can I return a negative value in main.cpp

Tags: c++, return-value, negative-number

As an assignment in school, we have to write a C++ program and returns different error codes in the `main`.

The problem is that we have to return `-2` if a specific error occurs but I have no idea how to return a negative value.

For example:

```
int main()
{ 
    int a = -2; 
    return a;
}
```

In windows this gives me a return value like: `42232684` and in Linux there is: `253`

Why `-2` is not allowed?

And how can I manage to get `-2`?

Comment: How do you check the return value?

Comment: You can't do it. Termination status is unsigned. Are you sure the assignment really wants this in the program's termination status, and not stdout?

Comment: @Barmar - seriously? Then why is `main` `int` not `unsinged` for example? Interesting, I've never thought about this.

Comment: The return value of int is not the same as the program's termination status. The termination status is 2 bytes, the return value is put into one byte of that. it gets converted to unsigned in the process.

Comment: @Barmar That would explain the result the OP gets on Linux, but not on Windows. Is this a Linux thing? Or a POSIX thing?

Comment: In windows its automatically printed out by the IDE. In linux i don't know how to display the return value but my university has a testing environment for such things. i hand in code and the system checks the return values and lets me know if they are like they should be.

Comment: On Unix, the termination status uses one byte for the signal that killed the process, and one byte for the exit code. It looks like Windows is simply converting the exit code to unsigned long.

Comment: According to the standard, the return value of `main()` is passed to `std::exit(int)`. From there, by C++11 § 18.5, "If status is zero or EXIT_SUCCESS, an implementation-defined form of the status successful termination is returned. If status is EXIT_FAILURE, an implementation-defined form of the status unsuccessful termination is returned. Otherwise the status returned is implementation-defined.". So if you're looking for a standard-manadated return value to the host OS, you're not going to find one.

Comment: On Linux you display the exit code with `echo $?`.

Comment: @Barmar: you are right. and linux converts it to unsigned char i think.

Comment: That's damn good question, especially for user, just signed in! This is really rare case :)

Comment: how to check the exit code? visual studio accepts the return of -2

Comment: @MichiKampl, on Linux, after executing `g++ source.cpp && ./a.out`  on the terminal you should run `echo $?` to get the return code. @Maher, run the executable from the command prompt and then run `echo %errorlevel%`.

Comment: [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/exit.html)

Comment: i still got -2 after doing that! it seems that it depends on system bits 32 and 64

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that what is returned to the OS is then interpreted by the OS shell as IT likes it, not  as your program likes.

the main function returns an int, and `return -2` is just what your program has to do.

253 is -2 in 2s complement onto 8 bits.

The problem -here- is a mismatch between the C++ specs (`int main()`) and the way the shell use it. But it does not depend on the program.

The assignment itself is a trap.

Comment: I could finally get an answer to this problem from my Tutor.

Comment: it was a missunderstanding. it doesnt work to return real negative values and the test system will accept 253 as return value. thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 4):

From C++11 standard 18.5/8:

> If status is zero or EXIT_SUCCESS, an
>   implementation-defined form of the status successful termination is returned. If status is EXIT_FAILURE, an implementation-defined form of the status unsuccessful termination is returned.
>   Otherwise the status returned is implementation-defined.

Thus is it completely compliant that you get different results for different platforms, and/or compilers.

Comment: Your first sentence is in contradiction with the quoted section from the standard. The latter states that the return value is always implementation defined, while your introductory sentence suggests that sometimes it isn't.

Answer (score 2):

Unix, and linux are limited to 8 bit return codes, -2 is 0xfe. Which your shell will understand to be 254 when you `echo $?`

You're expected to give a return code between 0 and 255.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status

> on POSIX-compatible exit statuses are restricted to values 0-255, the
>   range of an unsigned 8-bit integer.

Comment: 2s complement of -2 for an 8-bit value is 0xfe. Not sure what you're trying to say here...

Comment: it makes no difference if i type -2 and let the system do the work to convert it to 254 or just type 254 or 0xfe...