# Multiple %ERRORLEVEL%

Tags: batch-file

I am having some issues with my current Batch script to check the verison of windows and then activate with a certain key. This is what i have got so far

```
@echo on

:7

cscript /nologo c:\windows\system32\slmgr.vbs /xpr | findstr /i /c:"Windows(R) 7"> NUL 2>&1

if [%errorlevel%]==[0] (

    cscript /nologo c:\windows\system32\slmgr.vbs /xpr | findstr /i /c:" will expire "> NUL 2>&1

    if [%errorlevel%]==[0] (

    slmgr.vbs /ipk XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX
    slmgr.vbs /ato

    ) else (GOTO END)

) else (GOTO VISTA)

:VISTA

cscript /nologo c:\windows\system32\slmgr.vbs /xpr | findstr /i /c:"Windows(R) Vista"> NUL 2>&1

if [%errorlevel%]==[0] (

    cscript /nologo c:\windows\system32\slmgr.vbs /xpr | findstr /i /c:" will expire "> NUL 2>&1

    if [%errorlevel%]==[0] (

    slmgr.vbs /ipk XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX
    slmgr.vbs /ato

    ) else (GOTO END)

) else (GOTO END)

:END

pause

exit /b
```

Comment: Need to use [delayedexpansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html). `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` and `!errorlevel!`

Comment: You could also use `if not errorlevel 1` and not need delayedexpansion

Comment: @MattWilliamson  That is an alternate method, but it does have one stipulation.  If the errorcode returned is negative it will evaluate as true.  Also for clarification, `if not errorlevel 1` is really saying `if not errorlevel >= 1`.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution 1: Delayed Expansion

The solution of [David Ruhmann](https://stackoverflow.com/users/891976/david-ruhmann) applied on the example batch file:

```
@echo on
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

:7

cscript /nologo c:\windows\system32\slmgr.vbs /xpr | findstr /i /c:"Windows(R) 7"> NUL 2>&1

if [!errorlevel!]==[0] (

    cscript /nologo c:\windows\system32\slmgr.vbs /xpr | findstr /i /c:" will expire "> NUL 2>&1

    if [!errorlevel!]==[0] (

    slmgr.vbs /ipk XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX
    slmgr.vbs /ato

    ) else (GOTO END)

) else (GOTO VISTA)

:VISTA

cscript /nologo c:\windows\system32\slmgr.vbs /xpr | findstr /i /c:"Windows(R) Vista"> NUL 2>&1

if [!errorlevel!]==[0] (

    cscript /nologo c:\windows\system32\slmgr.vbs /xpr | findstr /i /c:" will expire "> NUL 2>&1

    if [!errorlevel!]==[0] (

    slmgr.vbs /ipk XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX
    slmgr.vbs /ato

    ) else (GOTO END)

) else (GOTO END)

:END
endlocal

pause

exit /b
```

*Note:* The output of command `ver` can be also filtered by `findstr` as shown above with the various Windows strings (or version numbers) to find out [version of Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724832(v=vs.85).aspx). Using `ver` is faster than using

```
cscript /nologo c:\windows\system32\slmgr.vbs /xpr
```

as `ver` is an internal command.

---

### Solution 2: Testing Errorlevel

The solution provided by [Matt Williamson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2282445/matt-williamson) works also taking into account

- Documentation of [Findstr](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490907.aspx) by Microsoft
- Support article [Testing for a Specific Error Level in Batch Files](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/69576) by Microsoft
- Stack Overflow question [How to conditionally take action if FINDSTR fails to find a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8530976/how-to-conditionally-take-action-if-findstr-fails-to-find-a-string)
- and the fact that **FINDSTR** does not return negative values on exit. Why?
  See Stack Overflow question [C++: How can I return a negative value in main.cpp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18890534/c-how-can-i-return-a-negative-value-in-main-cpp)
  No programmer should exit ever an application with a negative value. It is simply a bad idea.

The solution of [Matt Williamson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2282445/matt-williamson) applied on the example batch file:

```
@echo on

:7

cscript /nologo c:\windows\system32\slmgr.vbs /xpr | findstr /i /c:"Windows(R) 7"> NUL 2>&1

if not errorlevel 1 (

    cscript /nologo c:\windows\system32\slmgr.vbs /xpr | findstr /i /c:" will expire "> NUL 2>&1

    if not errorlevel 1 (

    slmgr.vbs /ipk XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX
    slmgr.vbs /ato

    ) else (GOTO END)

) else (GOTO VISTA)

:VISTA

cscript /nologo c:\windows\system32\slmgr.vbs /xpr | findstr /i /c:"Windows(R) Vista"> NUL 2>&1

if not errorlevel 1 (

    cscript /nologo c:\windows\system32\slmgr.vbs /xpr | findstr /i /c:" will expire "> NUL 2>&1

    if not errorlevel 1 (

    slmgr.vbs /ipk XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX
    slmgr.vbs /ato

    ) else (GOTO END)

) else (GOTO END)

:END

pause

exit /b
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to arrange your script:

`&&` signifies errorlevel 0 and conversely `||` signifies errorlevel 1

```
@echo off

cscript /nologo c:\windows\system32\slmgr.vbs /xpr | findstr /i /c:"Windows(R) 7"> NUL 2>&1 && set num=1XXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX
cscript /nologo c:\windows\system32\slmgr.vbs /xpr | findstr /i /c:"Windows(R) Vista"> NUL 2>&1 && set num=2XXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX

cscript /nologo c:\windows\system32\slmgr.vbs /xpr | findstr /i /c:" will expire "> NUL 2>&1 && (

    slmgr.vbs /ipk %num%
    slmgr.vbs /ato

)

pause

exit /b
```